# Having a double question mark query for one email url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, jquery, url

I've added a question mark in url on marketing cloud because I want a specific code added in every email of the journey.

When I send my email the usual query added after the launch give me two exclamation mark :

- Initial URL : **URL+anchor?specificquerycode=xxx**
- URL after email send : **URL**?UTM+querycode1=**anchor**?**specificquerycode=WPBDP3**

That seems to change the order of some codes and it's adding me two exclamation mark.

Can you help me to solution this please.

PS : I saw this

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused by a known issue in SFMC Web Analytics Connector:
[RedirectTo() with an anchor tag with Web Analytics Connector enabled does not move the anchor tag to the end](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5kCrAAI/redirectto-with-an-anchor-tag-with-web-analytics-connector-enabled-does-not-move-the-anchor-tag-to-the-end)

There are no simple workarounds, as the WAC parameters are appended at sendtime, hence you don't have any control of them within the email itself. I will advise you to log in to the issue tracker, and report it. The more people report an issue, the higher is the probability that it will be addressed and fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As your link say, the anchor seems to be the source of my trouble : with an other link, everything is ok without anchor : **URL**?**specifiquerycode=xx**&UTM&querycode1 It seems there is no way to make working it with an anchor.. maybe someone else have a solution ?

Comment: @myunkownpseudo - unfortunately no, there is to my knowledge no feasible workaround, if you want to keep the anchor in your URL